# Can't make JSP display model values. Simple Spring MVC example

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Followed several examples and still can't make it work.

Using a basic Spring MVC, trying to display some data returned by a controller. (Using Spring 4.3.9, Tomcat 8.5.20 and Chromium)

Here is the project tree:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── mywebapp
        │       ├── config
        │       │   ├── MyWebAppInitializer.java
        │       │   ├── RootConfig.java
        │       │   └── WebConfig.java
        │       └── web
        │           └── HomeController.java
        ├── resources
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── views
                │   └── home.jsp
                └── web.xml
```

1) MyWebAppInitializer.java

```
package mywebapp.config;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

2) RootConfig.java is an empty class, no beans.

3) WebConfig.java - I used TWO versions of this config file:
**version A:**

```
package mywebapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("mywebapp.config")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**version B:** - The difference is only in the viewResolver()

```
package mywebapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("mywebapp.config")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

4) HomeController.java

```
package mywebapp.web;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
    public String home(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("xyz","this is my message");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

5) home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<c:out value="${xyz}" />
<br>${xyz}
</body>
</html>
```

6) web.xml - is "empty", wasn't modified after being created by maven archetype.

For BOTH versions of `WebConfig.java` the output is the same:

```
Hello World!

${xyz} 
${xyz}
```

Please help!

Comment: have you tried returning ModelAndView and using "forward:index"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two step solution:

A) Delete `web.xml`created by maven archetype.

B) Add the following maven plugin to `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```